# JasperReports not showing UTF-8 characters - MacOSX

Tags: encoding, jasper-reports

I have a csv file encoded in UTF-8(no BOM) and I want to setup a simple report using JasperReports. After setting up the datasource I find that non ASCII characters are not displayed correctly.
I changed *net.sf.jasperreports.export.character.encoding* to UTF-8 but it didn't help at all.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

After a little more than 1 hour I find out:

- [MacOSX Java uses MacOSRoman as its default encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_Roman#Application_notes)
- iReport shell script doesn't use JAVA_OPTS
- iReport passes JVM args through netbeans nbexec command line arguments.

So, in order to get iReport to start Java with file.encoding=UTF-8 I:

1. Opened iReport package
2. found /Applications/Jaspersoft iReport Designer.app/Contents/Resources/ireport/etc/ireport.conf
3. Appended -J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 to default_options, which is passed as [netbeans nbexec command line arguments](http://platform.netbeans.org/articles/installation.html).

   Another option for [3] would be to set $args variable which is passed as nbexec parameters also by the ireport initialization script.

Just sharing because it took me a while to figure and I couldn't find any help on google.